# How to search a node filtering by an array field using multiple values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I store some values inside an array of a node and I would like to filter it using more than a single value. How could I do that?

Here it is my node:

```
CREATE (t:Test { value:["a","b","c"] } );
CREATE (t:Test { value:["a","b","d"] } );
CREATE (t:Test { value:["a","b","x"] } );
CREATE (t:Test { value:["a","y","z"] } );
CREATE (t:Test { value:["a","f","k"] } );
```

I would like to create a query that retrieves only items that "a" and "b" are inside values column.

The query below is not working but is close to what I would like to do.

```
MATCH (c:Test) WHERE ["a", "b"] IN c.value RETURN c
```

I know that I could split it using two "IN" commands (example below) but I would to like to avoid creating dynamic queries on my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MATCH (c:Test)
WHERE ALL(x IN ["a","b"] WHERE x IN c.value)
RETURN c.value
```